# Non Transactional Execution Within a TransactionScope

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, transactionscope

I am executing multiple stored procedures from within a TransactionScope.  Is there any way to execute a SqlCommand (while still within the scope of the using statement) but remove it from the transaction?

There are SqlCommands executed before and after it that do need to be within the one transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new SqlConnection instance with the '[Enlist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.enlist.aspx)' connection parameter set to 'false'

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder csBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(existingCon.ConnectionString);
csBuilder.Enlist = false;
SqlConnection newConnection = new SqlConnection(csBuilder.ConnectionString);     
SqlCommand commandNotInTheTx = newConnection.CreateCommand();
```

Comment: Also, if you know that a given connection should always avoid ambient transactions, you can just put 'Enlist=false' in your connection string in your config and avoid any extra coding or connection management.   This link is for .NET 1.1 but the enlistment part is accurate still, I believe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720033(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to open another connection and execute your statement there. But beware: that statement will not see any changes from the uncommitted transaction.

Comment: The statement is already has a seperate connection, but because it is with the using statement of the TransactionScope .NET attempts to put it inside the same transaction.  Any idea how to create a connection that does not use the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new scope and specify the [`Supress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscopeoption.aspx) option.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, transaction enlistment requires connections to be members of the same connection pool. If you use a slightly different connection string for the second connection (perhaps by using a different `Application Name`), that might allow it to bypass enlistment.

Just be careful you don't accidentally start using distributed transactions and DTC.